# ValueError while trying to access stdout using pytest and capsys

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest, stdout, valueerror

Trying to test stdout of a local method in an object that verifies users account.

As an example,

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar, baz):
        self.bar = bar
        if baz:
            self.something = self.load_something()
        else:
            print('Error initializing')

    def load_something(self):
        return ''

    def make_subprocess_call(self):
        return 'stdout', 'stderr'
    
    def confirm_something(self):
        subprocess_stdout, subprocess_stderr = self.make_subprocess_call()
        if subprocess_stdout:
            print('good output')
        else:
            print('err output', subprocess_stderr)
```

Then to test:

```py
from Foo_Class_File import Foo
import mock
import pytest

@mock.patch('Foo_Class_File.Foo.load_something', return_value = {'a': 'b'})
@mock.patch('Foo_Class_File.Foo.make_subprocess_call', return_value=('more stdout', 'more_stderr'))
def test_confirm_something(testdir, capsys):
    test_foo = Foo(testdir, True)
    test_foo.confirm_something()
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert out == 'more stdout'
    assert err == 'more_stderr'
```

Then running:

```sh
python3 -m pytest test_foo_file.py
```

gives:

```
============================================================================== FAILURES ===============================================================================
_______________________________________________________________________ test_confirm_something ________________________________________________________________________

testdir = <MagicMock name='make_subprocess_call' id='140533346667632'>, capsys = <MagicMock name='load_something' id='140533346970400'>

    @mock.patch('Foo_Class_File.Foo.load_something', return_value = {'a': 'b'})
    @mock.patch('Foo_Class_File.Foo.make_subprocess_call', return_value=('more stdout', 'more_stderr'))
    def test_confirm_something(testdir, capsys):
        test_foo = Foo(testdir, True)
        test_foo.confirm_something()
>       out, err = capsys.readouterr()
E       ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

blah.py:10: ValueError
------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------
good output
======================================================================= short test summary info =======================================================================
FAILED test_foo_file.py::test_confirm_something - ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
========================================================================== 1 failed in 0.11s ==========================================================================
```

I'm just really confused because it says that is capturing the stdout?

I think it has to do with instantiating the object and then calling the method, as I have no problem capturing with capsys if there is just the object, but as soon as I try to instantiate it and call a method, what you see above it what happens. I couldn't find a similar case online or in the documentation, not for lack of trying (or perhaps my google foo is weak today).

Apologies if I am doing something silly but at this point I am concerned for the safety of my keyboard and figured I would reach out. Any help/suggestions are appreciated. You can run this test case I posted, it should give you the same error as posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you supplied patch decorators, but did not add the respective arguments to the test function. This would be correct:

```py
@mock.patch('Foo_Class_File.Foo.load_something', return_value = {'a': 'b'})
@mock.patch('Foo_Class_File.Foo.make_subprocess_call', return_value=('more stdout', 'more_stderr'))
def test_confirm_something(mocked_call, mocked_load, testdir, capsys):  # note the additional arguments
    test_foo = Foo(testdir, True)
    test_foo.confirm_something()
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert out == 'good output\n'
    assert err == ''
```

Or, alternatively:

```py
@mock.patch('Foo_Class_File.Foo.load_something')
@mock.patch('Foo_Class_File.Foo.make_subprocess_call')
def test_confirm_something(mocked_call, mocked_load, testdir, capsys):
    mocked_call.return_value = ('more stdout', 'more_stderr')
    mocked_load.return_value = {'a': 'b'}
    test_foo = Foo(testdir, True)
    ...
```

What happened in your code is that the fixtures `testdir` and `capsys` has been used as the mocked parameters instead (which are expected as the first arguments in the test function), leading to both being a mock object instead of the fixture.

*Side note*: it would be nice if pytest gave a warning in this case, something like "You are using a fixture name as a name for a patched object, maybe you forgot to add the patched object argument?"...

Note that I have replaced the assertions in your example code with the assertions that would actually pass using your code.

Comment: In retrospect I probably should've noticed testdir and capsys getting assigned those MagicMock types pertaining to the decorators.  In any case, thanks for your help and the detailed solution :).

Comment: In retrospect all seems to be more clear ;) Glad I could help!

Comment: actually, equally hilarious follow up, I just switched off the decorators and installed the mocker fixture, but appreciate the help in understanding pytest :)